# Setting Nodejs ENV from DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I understand that modules within nodejs are synchronous, but what I am having issues with is within that module it is doing an asynchronous call to DynamoDB using the aws-sdk. So therefore the module finishs before the async call to DynamoDB has, and allows the rest of the nodejs application to continue.

The module I have put together is meant to get environment variables from DynamoDB, and set them for use within the APP, this is meant to be done once and at run time.

This is a nodejs lambda function, so it needs to be done at run time and not every time the function is run.

Here is my code for the module:

```
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    var config = require("../config/config.js");

    module.exports = {

    setEnv: function(){

    AWS.config.update({
        region: config.awsregion,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWSDYNAMOACCESS,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSDYNAMOSECRET,
        sslEnabled: true,
        maxRetries: 5

    }); 

    var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    var table = config.envTable;

    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "type": config.envType
        }
    };

    db.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {

        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        process.env.APIKEY = data.Item.tkey;
        process.env.KEYEXPIRE = data.Item.tkeyexpire;

        }
    });
}
    };

    module.exports.load = module.exports.setEnv
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each Lambda invocation is not going to share the same environment. AWS will spin up and shutdown underlying servers to run your Lambda function as needed. What you are trying to do is not going to work.

Comment: Under high load, it should use the same spun up instance(s) right? I understand that if the lambda function isn't invoked frequently enough that it will be doing a cold start every time.

Comment: Under high load they might add more instances to handle the load. I see what you are trying to do now, and it might work. If you are using the NodeJS 4.3 environment in Lambda you should be able to use the promise support in the AWS SDK to get a promise back from the DynamoDB call, then wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks. I have setup a promise, but not really sure what I am doing. Do you have any example code how to wait for the promise to be resolved?

Comment: You should bundle your env variables at build time with your function and have it available locally to your function. What you are trying to do here can be very problematic not only from lambda's hot/cold startups but from cost perspective especially with dynamodb.